# No Viable Alternative at character ' '

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Hi i am getting the following error in this code
/*
Class : CreateMobileChatterCntrl 
Description : Post Chatter on Contact.
Developed by : Harish Khatri(Appirio Offshore)
Created Date : June 2, 2012
*/

```
public without sharing class CreateMobileChatterCntrl {
  public final Id ContactID{get;set;}
  public String message{get;set;}
  public boolean isSuccess{get;set;}
  public boolean throwError{get;set;}
  public String deviceType{get;set;}
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    //constructor
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  public CreateMobileChatterCntrl() {
    throwError = false;
    isSuccess = false;
    if( ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id') != null){
      ContactID = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    }
    String userAgent = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('USER-AGENT');
    if(userAgent.contains('iPhone')) 
      deviceType = 'iPhone';
    //else if(userAgent.contains('Android')) deviceType = 'Android';  
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    // Post the chatter on contact
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  public Pagereference save() {

    if(message == null || message ==''){
      throwError = true;
      return null;
    }

    FeedItem feedItem = new FeedItem();
    feedItem.ParentId = ContactID;
    feedItem.Body = message;

    try {

      insert feedItem;
      isSuccess = true;

    } catch(Exception e){}
   return null;//new PageReference('/' + ContactID);
  }

  public Pagereference cancel() {
    return new PageReference('/' + ContactID);
  }
}
```

public final Id ContactID{get;set;} at this line i am getting the error No Viable Alternative at character ' '.can any one please help why i am getting this error??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some of the single quote characters in your class file are invalid --- perhaps because you copied and pasted the code from somewhere else. I've had this happen many times before when I've copied code from elsewhere. Starting with the quotes in: message == '' , i'd delete the single quotes, retype them, and resave your file. Repeat for all single quotes (or do a find and replace).

Comment: Find and replace wouldn't work if the bad single quotes were visually identical, but used a different code-point.